# Handling Parse 64KB limit

Tags: parse-platform

We are using Parse to send out Push notifications using the Parse REST API. We compute the audience of the push notification based on dynamic user data such as user's current location. And in our Production system, we observe that there are times when this user base can be quite high given the time of the day. During such times, we have seen the ParseException:
org.parse4j.ParseException: Neither where clause nor data may exceed 64KB

This is because the where clause has a large number of "installation ids" or "device tokens" specified as we find a large number of users in a given location.

I understand that Channels / Parse Audience is a way to deal with larger sets of users. But this requires me to store the dynamic data like a user's current location in the Parse database as part of the Installation metadata.
My questions are:

1. Is it the right way to implement it if we decide to store user location in Parse, which will also mean that we would need to update this Installation object per user very frequently.
2. Is it advisable to just send push notifications via Parse in chunks, that is first to a set of 2000 users, then the next 1000 etc.
3. Is there any other way to handle such a case?

Comment: both are sensible approaches, batching means you don't over-share user details...